# How to install WiFi driver in Debian 9?

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers

I installed Debian 9.

Now I need to install WiFi card driver. But, I couldn't find a working one on my system.

These are my devices listed by command `lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:1c1a] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c4b] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] [10de:0df5] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
04:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 04)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
```

---

**Question:** how to install wifi drivers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your WiFi card is apparently this one:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
```

It is supported by the `iwlwifi` driver, which is included in the standard kernel package. Your adapter has been supported this way since kernel version 2.6.36. With some kernels, the driver module might be named `iwlagn` instead.

What you need is the *firmware* file for the adapter. In Debian 9, you'll first need to [enable the non-free part of Debian repository](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) if you didn't enable it when installing Debian in the first place. (Non-free here means "you don't get the source code for it", not "you must pay for it".)

then install the `firmware-iwlwifi` package using your favorite package management utility, then reboot and the driver should be auto-loaded and ready for use.

Comment: Firmware is in the "non-free" Repository. If this is not installed into the sources list firmware-iwlwifi will not be available to the OP.

Comment: @arochester Intel 1030 should work with the included kernel module, adding `non-free` isn't required.

Comment: @GAD3R The *driver* is free and included in the main repository, but the *firmware* is in non-free, because you don't get the source code for it. Debian is pretty serious about the principles of free software.

Comment: after install driver wifi is working and connected to my wifi but when I search google in chrome then it shows this site can't be reached @telcoM

Comment: So, the driver apparently works and the next step is connectivity troubleshooting, which should be a different question altogether. Are you getting an IP address that matches the configuration of your WiFi network? Are you getting valid DNS server address(es)? Is the WiFi base station configured to restrict network access unless the client is specifically whitelisted or otherwise verified?

Comment: @telcoM can you explain in brief and in a simple way or give me a link from where I can understand

Answer (score 0):

I download `firmware-atheros_20210315-3_all.deb` [1](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/all/firmware-atheros/download). Then just enter the Download folder and type at the console:

```
sudo dpkg -i firmware-atheros_20210315-3_all.deb
```

Тhen restart, and WiFi appear as а menu in Network Manager.

Comment: Just curious, did this resolve your issue with a `Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)` as in the question, or with a different controller? I ask because "Atheros" isn't apparently related, but maybe it's not obvious. Thanks!